# Join table with group by year and base on that year count other table particular record with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two table of employee, one is for employee detail with joining date and other table is for employee termination detail with resign date.

I need to create a report in that I have to count current active emplyee. That means I need to display all employee list who is currently working on this company and not resigned. I want to display these records group by year.

**Employee table:**

```
sr   employee_name    join_year
1    test employee      2015
2    John Smith         2015
3    ABC employee       2016
4    Axel Alex          2017
5    Bhatt Charya       2017
```

**Termination table :**

```
sr   emplyee name    resign_year
1    John smith        2016
2    Bhatt Charya      2017
```

**Report should look like below :**

```
 sr     year    active_employee
 1      2015        1
 2      2016        1
 3      2017        1
```

In above example you can see we have 5 total employee in 1st table but 2 employee resign in 2016 and 2017 so the report should like above.

In query I need to check year like one employee join on 2014 and resign on same year then it should not count, join date is in 1st table and resign date is in termination_table. So how to match that and how to make a query ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired resuls.

Comment: I did it bro...

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT join_year AS year, count(employee_name) AS active_employee 
  FROM Employee 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
      FROM Termination 
      WHERE Employee.employee_name = Termination.employee_name)
  GROUP BY join_year
  ORDER BY join_year
```

Comment: @David please help me know weather this query worked or not.

Comment: If it solved your problem please mark the answer as 'Accepted'